# How to calculate Cumulative Sum with Groupby in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate cumulative sum with groupby using Pandas's DataFrame. However, I don't get expected output.

My Source Code:

```
import pandas as pd
Employee = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
        ['CSE', 'CSE', 'EEE', 'EEE', 'CE', 'CE', 'ME', 'ME'],
        ['Cat-1', 'Cat-2', 'Cat-1', 'Cat-2', 'Cat-1', 'Cat-2', 'Cat-1', 'Cat-2']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(Employee, names=['Name', 'Dept', 'Category'])

Scale = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3]
Salary = [100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 200, 300]

df = pd.DataFrame({'scale': Scale,
               'salary': Salary},
              index=index)

df1 = df.groupby(['Category', 'scale']).cumsum()
print(df1)
```

Expected Output:

```
Cat-1    1         100
         2         500
         3         800
Cat-2    1         100
         2         300
         3         900
```

Obtained Result:

```
Name Dept Category        
A    CSE  Cat-1        100
B    CSE  Cat-2        200
C    EEE  Cat-1        300
D    EEE  Cat-2        500
E    CE   Cat-1        600
F    CE   Cat-2        600
G    ME   Cat-1       1000
H    ME   Cat-2       1200
```

Groupby doesn't work. However, if I use `sum()` (i.e. `df1 = df.groupby(['Category', 'scale']).sum()`) instead of `cumsum()`, groupby works perfectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple entries for each group so you need to aggregate the data twice, in other words, use `groupby` twice. Once to get the sum for each group and once to calculate the cumulative sum of these sums.

It can be done as follows:

```
df.groupby(['Category','scale']).sum().groupby('Category').cumsum()
```

Note that the `cumsum` should be applied on groups as partitioned by the `Category` column only to get the desired result.

Comment: this gives me an error, just FYI. I think it's because pandas can't find the `Category` column in the first groupby, since it's now in the index.

Comment: @colorlessgreenidea: If the column you want to group by is in the index then you can use `.reset_index()` first.